# Identify the date at which an email was sent out in the first place

Tags: email, parsing

I am trying to recreate the same functionality that came with OhLife (daily journaling web app fueled by daily email reminders - unfortunately closed off) and am facing a challenge: so far I've dedicated a hash to every email I sent out, the hash being stored in the database allowed me upon receiving an answer from the user to safely reconcile the email to its user and the related day.
I just realized that OhLife had found a way to actually rely on a single email address per user to manage it, which would also help me power my next feature: proactive daily entry without necessarily having to answer the daily reminder.

Could it be that they only relied on parsing the subject of the email (formatted along the lines of "It's Mon, Mar 23...")? I can't help but feel that might not be ideal as it is depending on the user not changing anything in the email subject, yet it's the best solution I came up with so far.

Comment: The `Date` header is the date and time the message was originally posted to the network. [RFC 1036 #2.1.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1036). I don't understand the rest of this waffle.

Comment: Sorry for the waffle. I am looking for a reliant way to get the date of the email I sent out, not the date of the reply itself. The `Date` header only provides the latter as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the replies: I think what you want to look at is the unique message ID of the email and not the date. You can set this message ID yourself when sending out the initial e-mail. The reply of the user will then have a "in reply to" header.

The headers according to [RFC2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) which are probably interesting for you are:

- message-id
- in-reply-to

Another approach would be to give each email a unique "reply-to" address. When using this in combination with a catch-all address you could identify the thread by looking at the unique e-mail address it was sent to.

In any case I think it will be combination of different "signals" depending on your use-case. I could think of

- in-response-to header
- unique inbound address for each user
- unique inbound address for each thread
- look at the "from" addresses to identify the user (not secure)